# How to give left-handed neutrinos alone Majorana mass?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model, grand-unification

The Wikipedia page on [Georgi–Glashow model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgi%E2%80%93Glashow_model#Breaking_SU(5)) says

> Fermions transforming as a 1 under SU(5) are now thought to be necessary because of the evidence for neutrino oscillations, unless a way is found to introduce a tiny Majorana coupling for the left-handed neutrinos.

This text tries to explain how the $$(1,2)_{-1/2}$$ of left-handed lepton (with a upper component of the doublet as left-handed neutrino) and $$(1,1)_{0}$$  as right-handed neutrino, can get a mass.

**My question**

How many ways can $(1,2)_{-1/2}$ and $(1,1)_{0}$ can get a mass?

It seems to me that

1. $(1,1)_{0}$ alone can get a Majorana mass.
2. $(1,2)_{-1/2}$ and $(1,1)_{0}$ together can get a Dirac mass.
3. Is there any difficulty for $(1,2)_{-1/2}$ alone (say a upper component of the doublet as left-handed neutrino) to get a Majorana mass? I do not see an immediate no go reason. But Wikipedia seems to say this is a big new discovery? See Wikipedia: "unless a way is found to introduce a tiny Majorana coupling for the left-handed neutrinos." Why?

The original text goes like:
[image]

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/96392/weinberg-dimension-5-operator).

Comment: Can you explain this part: 3). Is there any difficulty for (1,2)−1/2 alone (say a upper component of the doublet as left-handed neutrino) to get a Majorana mass? I do not see an immediate no go reason. But Wikipedia seems to say this is a big new discovery? See Wikipedia: "unless a way is found to introduce a tiny Majorana coupling for the left-handed neutrinos." Why?

Comment: I am OK with 1) and 2) already. thanks!

Comment: So your link indeed used dimension 5 operator to give mass to L neutrino alone, agree?

Comment: Agree. Yes. Many insist on renormalizability.

Comment: Sorry, what about renormalizability? The dimension 5 operator is not renormalizable? (which also means the dimension 5 operator is irrelevant at low energy?) thanks~

Comment: Yes, the operator is not renormalizable. It might arise as a low energy effective operator of a mystery theory.