# Majorana mass matrix seesaw and renormalizable interactions

Tags: mass, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model, majorana-fermions

Sometimes the general seesaw matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix} M_L & M_1\\ M_2 & M_R \end{pmatrix}$$

and its just said that in order to get renormalizable interactions one must impose the condition $M_L=0$. Why is this so?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yes, indeed it is something I have studied myself in the past during my Master Thesis degree, but I found myself thinking on the 'why' is it so after all recently studying seesaws and the efect on neutrino oscillations of ultra-light dark fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is virtually answered in [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/96406/66086).

The SU(2)×U(1) gauge-invariant fermion bilinears corresponding to each term of the matrix have their origins in the terms of dimension [d],
$$
M_L:   ~~~~~ \frac{1}{v}\left(  L ^T i \sigma _2  \cdot \tilde\phi^* ~~\tilde \phi \cdot L^c \right)  \qquad  [5],\\
M_1: \qquad\qquad  \qquad y_1 \overline{L}\cdot \tilde{\phi}~ R  \qquad [4],\\
M_2: \qquad\qquad  \qquad y_2  \overline{R}~ \tilde{\phi}^* \cdot L \qquad [4],\\
M_R: \qquad \qquad   M  R ^T  i \sigma _2  C   R                  \qquad [3].
$$

All fermion bilinears contribute dimension [3], and each Higgs,  providing the v.e.v., contributes [1]. The non-diagonal ones are SM-like Dirac masses. The $M_R$ is a huge non-SM lepton number (doubly)violating Majorana one, and

- the $M_L$ is the famous dimension [5], so nonrenormalizable, Weinberg operator. It too is a Majorana mass violating lepton number by 2.

Comment: So, it is due to be a non-renormalizable GUT-like term outside the SM? Can't it be non-zero in theories BSM?

Comment: Sure. It has the d.o.f. and gauge symmetries of the SM, but people were smitten by the SM because it was renormalizable, when it emerged. Something happening at scales far above *v* , so, BSM or GUT-like, could produces it as a "low-energy" effective lagrangian one .